# L2 Norm of Inverse of Non-square Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, inverse

Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ with $n<m$.

Given that $\|A\|_2 = \gamma_0$ and $AA^T$ is invertible, can we find any equality/upper bound for $\|(AA^T)^{-1}\|_2$ in terms of $\gamma_0$?

For the case that $A$ is an invertible square matrix, I can simply do that. But, I couldn't find the relation for non-square $A$ matrix, if there is any.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what's $\gamma_0$?

Comment: you can get lower bound in terms of $\gamma_0$

Comment: @Vim it is L2 norm of matrix $A$ as stated above. That is; $\|A\|_2=\gamma_0$.

Comment: @runaround How can we get that lower bound? Could you give me some details, hints etc. to find that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use $$(AA^T)^{-1}(AA^T) = I$$
and the $l_2$ norm property
$$ ||AB||_2 \le ||A||_2||B||_2$$

Comment: Well, this is OK. It was straigthforward to find lower bound with these hints. However, I realized that I need either an upper bound or equality. So, I edited the question.

Comment: Otherway around is likely a false.

Comment: So, you mean it is not likely to have an expression for upper bound?

Comment: The upper bould is limited by the minimal of eigenvalues of $AA^T$, and is not related to spectral.